# Find first three closest points from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Having original pandas dataframe containing 2 coordinates x_1 and x_2 without values:

```
    x_1  x_2
0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  0.0
2  2.0  0.2
3  2.5  1.5
4  1.5  2.0
5 -2.0 -2.0
```

and other "calibration" dataframe that contains coordinate points with values:

```
    x_1  x_2  value
0  0.1  0.1    5.0
1  1.0 -2.0    6.0
2  2.0  0.4    3.0
3  2.5  2.5    4.0
4  1.5  1.0   -2.0
5  0.0  0.0    3.0
6  5.6  2.0    5.0
7  7.0  1.0   -3.0
8  8.0 -2.0   -4.0
```

I would like to find values for original dataframe, basing on calibration dataframe, using plane equation, so I need to find 3 closest points. Then I can find value for each row in original dataframe. How to find 3 nearest points from other pandas dataframe?

My trying code is following:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import scipy
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

# Define input dataframe
df = {'x_1':    [0.0,1.0,2.0,2.5,1.5,-2.0],
        'x_2':  [0.0,0.0,0.2,1.5,2.0,-2.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns= ['x_1','x_2'])
print("Dataframe is:\n",df)

# In the below lines define calibration dataframe
print("Defining calibration dataframe...")
calibration = {'x_1':    [0.1,1.0,2.0,2.5,1.5,0.0,5.6,7.0,8.0],
        'x_2':          [0.1,-2.0,0.4,2.5,1.0,0.0,2.0,1.0,-2.0],
        'value':        [5.0,6.0,3.0,4.0,-2.0,3.0,5.0,-3.0,-4.0]}
calibration = pd.DataFrame(calibration,columns= ['x_1','x_2','value'])
print("Calibration dataframe is:\n",calibration)

# distances = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(df[['x_1','x_2']], df[['x_1','x_2']], metric='euclidean')
# print(distances)

df['dist'] = np.sqrt( (df.x_1-calibration.x_1)**2 + (df.x_2-calibration.x_2)**2)

df['first_closest_x_1']=0
df['first_closest_x_2']=0
df['value_first_closest']=0
df['second_closest_x_1']=0
df['second_closest_x_2']=0
df['value_second_closest']=0
df['third_closest_x_1']=0
df['third_closest_x_2']=0
df['value_third_closest']=0

# new_df=df.iloc[(df['x_1']-calibration['x_1']).abs().argsort()[:]]
# new_df = pd.DataFrame(mat, index=df['value'], columns=df['value']) 
print("New_df:\n",new_df)

print("Values were calculated!")
```

Expected output is following:

```
    x_1 x_2 first_closest_x_1   first_closest_x_2   value_first_closest second_closest_x_1  second_closest_x_2  value_second_closest    third_closest_x_1   third_closest_x_2   value_third_closest
0   0   0   0   0   3   0.1 0.1 5   1.5 1   -2
1   1   0   0.1 0.1 5   0   0   3   2   0.4 3
2   2   0.2 2   0.4 3   1.5 1   -2  0.1 0.1 5
3   2.5 1.5 2.5 2.5 4   1.5 1   -2  2   0.4 3
4   1.5 2   1.5 1   -2  2.5 2.5 4   2   0.4 3
5   0.1 0.1 0   0   3   0.1 0.1 5   1   -2  6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two datasets are not too big to calculate pairwise distance, you could outer merge two datasets, calculate the distance for each pair, rank them in each group. see code below (assuming `df1` is `df` and `df2` is `calibration`,

```
result  = (df1.reset_index()
              .assign(key=1)
              .merge(df2.assign(key=1), on='key')
              .drop('key',axis=1)
              .assign(dist=lambda df:np.sqrt((df.x_1_x-df.x_1_y)**2 + (df.x_2_x-df.x_2_y)**2))
              .assign(dist_rank = lambda df:df.groupby('index')['dist'].rank(method='first'))
              .loc[lambda df:df.dist_rank<=3])
```

result

```
index x_1_x x_2_x   x_1_y   x_2_y   value   dist    dist_rank
0   0.0 0.0 0.1 0.1 5.0 0.141421    2.0
0   0.0 0.0 1.5 1.0 -2.0    1.802776    3.0
0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.000000    1.0
1   0.0 1.0 0.1 0.1 5.0 0.905539    1.0
1   0.0 1.0 1.5 1.0 -2.0    1.500000    3.0
1   0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 1.000000    2.0
2   0.2 2.0 0.1 0.1 5.0 1.902630    2.0
2   0.2 2.0 1.5 1.0 -2.0    1.640122    1.0
2   0.2 2.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 2.009975    3.0
3   1.5 2.5 2.0 0.4 3.0 2.158703    3.0
3   1.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 4.0 1.000000    1.0
3   1.5 2.5 1.5 1.0 -2.0    1.500000    2.0
4   2.0 1.5 2.0 0.4 3.0 1.100000    2.0
4   2.0 1.5 2.5 2.5 4.0 1.118034    3.0
4   2.0 1.5 1.5 1.0 -2.0    0.707107    1.0
5   -2.0    -2.0    0.1 0.1 5.0 2.969848    2.0
5   -2.0    -2.0    1.0 -2.0    6.0 3.000000    3.0
5   -2.0    -2.0    0.0 0.0 3.0 2.828427    1.0
```

Comment: Two datasets will contain maximum ~200 rows, so your solution is interesting. But now how to convert it to format shown in my original question, in the way that the first closest point is in new column etc.?

Comment: Please provide the expected output example. It should not be a daunting task after this.

Comment: I added expected output to tail of my question.

Comment: I tried something like this, but it gives Nans:
`df['first_closest_x_1']=result['x_1_y'].loc[result['index'] & result['dist_rank']==1.0]`